# ASP.NET MVC Route: Product category and slug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, friendly-url

I have a ProductController for viewing products.
Products have a slug and a category.

I want the following pretty urls (examples)

```
URL                                               CONTROLLER ACTION                   PARAMETER
www.example.com/products                   -> ProductController.Products      :  "" (empty string)
www.example.com/products/phones            -> ProductController.Products      :  "phones"
www.example.com/products/phones/iPhone     -> ProductController.Details       :  "phones" &"iPhone"
```

Preferably implemented as route-attributes `[HttpGet("route-here")]`. But `routes.MapRoute` in `Startup.cs` is also ok.

Thanks.

**What i've tried**
The first 2 routes are currently working for me:

```
[HttpGet("products/{category?}")]
public ActionResult Products(string category)
```

But the last route does **not** seem to work:

```
[HttpGet("products/{category}/{slug}")]
public ActionResult Details(string category, string slug)
```

Comment: *What issues are you experiencing? What have you tried?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe I've answered this without making you try to solve it yourself, but here's the code

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [Route("products/{productType}")]
    public ActionResult Products(string productType)
    {

    }

    [Route("products/{productType}/{product}")]
    public ActionResult Details(string productType, string product)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: As you see in my updated question, i've already tried this. But i am an idiot. I was just overseeing some missing .ToLower(). My bad. Your answer is correct.